# Create new instance for every file - Paperclip Multiple File Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've noticed that a lot of multiple file uploads follow the logic that you have a Gallery or Album which has multiple image files within it. I'm hoping to go for something much simpler - basically I'd just like to be able to select multiple files on the new page, and have a completely new instance for each file be created, unrelated to anything else.

The idea is that it's an art website, you select up to 5 files to upload, and then just 5 images are submitted without relation to an album or gallery.

In my new.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form_for @dabble, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :art, :multiple =>:true %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm not sure what to do in my new controller action. By following the post http://www.travisberry.com/2013/02/simple-multi-file-uploads-with-paperclip/ 
this is what I have so far:

```
params[:dabble][:art].each do |art|
  @dabble = Dabble.new(:art => art)
  @dabble.save
end
```

But this just throws an ImageMagick error. Is it possible to just have the entire new action be called for as many files that are selected from the new action?

Comment: Can you just show the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Model:** AttachedItem

```
class AttachedItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :art, :styles => { :large => "800x800", :medium => "400x400>", :small => "200x200>" }
  attr_accessible :art, :art_file_name
end
```

**Model:** Dabble

```
class Dabble < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attached_items, :as => :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attached_items, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :attached_items_attributes
end
```

**Controller:** DabblesController

```
class DabblesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @dabble = Dabble.new(params[:dabble])
    if @dabble.save
      redirect_to action: "index"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**View:** new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @dabble, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
   <%= file_field_tag 'dabble_attached_items_art', :multiple =>:true, :name =>  "dabble[attached_items_attributes][][art]" %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

If `:multiple => true` doesn't work, then use `:multiple => "multiple"`.

Also, as IE doesn't support `multiple` attribute, the above example will allow to upload only one file in IE.

Hope it works :)

Comment: I'm fine with IE not supporting it haha. But, won't this create several attached files per one Dabble? I'm hoping for each selected image to create its own instance of a new Dabble. So you select 4 images, and it creates 4 new dabbles that upload.